# File object getting Null when using apache

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I am using Apache server for redirecting the secure request to our web server [tomcat], we had also use the Apache server for load balancing.

and further I describe that, we pass the file object to server for the processing.

so at server side we get the file object null every-time when we use the load balancing server technique, this happen when we work with the load balancing environment.

if any body having idea and knowledge in it that please share it with us?
What is the issue with this null pointer exception?

Comment: Is this about programming or about server configuration/troubleshooting?